# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDeployedCampaigns')

Tags: next.js, ethereum, solidity

Following is my code where I try to use one of factory methods in getInitialProps, but it is giving error, after i console logged factory, it is logged as ('false') whereas if i use it outside getInitialProps, it is not giving any error

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import factory from "../ethereum/factory";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

export default class getCampaigns extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps(props) {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log(factory);
    const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call();
    return {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```